# Pressing break while debugging in Visual Studio - annoying "Code Not Running"

Tags: visual-studio

How do you stop Visual Studio showing that annoying tab page whilst debugging after pressing break:

[image]

For the record - I can debug fine and alter code and resume running the code fine.  It's just a pain that it takes focus away from the code that you were looking at before you break the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This extension should do exactly what you want.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fdbb2036-471e-40a7-b20e-31f8fd5578fa

Comment: I am staggered that someone has kindly had to go to so much trouble to disable such an annoying feature of Visual Studio - Microsoft take note!!  Thanks for the info :)